# Understanding iPhone Provisioning Portal and how it works?

Tags: iphone, xcode

The process of provisioning portal, certificates, provisioning profiles, etc are still confusing me. I read apple's documentations and googled a lot about it.. Nothing helped me..

I have a Mac and an iPhone. How can I install the application which I developed in Xcode in my device?

Could anyone give a simple steps to understand the work flow of Provisioning Portal process?

Thanks

Comment: The process is really not that hard, tho it involves a series of backs and forth between the Provisioning Portal, Keychain and finally Xcode, but there are even youtube videos showing you the whole process. Perhaps if you tell us what steps did you do, we can identify a mistake. Reason behind this is that there are already multiple tutorials out there. :)

Comment: Hey.. Thanks for your info. Actually my problem is the lot of steps in this work flow. I can not figure out where to start, and how to drive the flow correctly. Sorry for that.. Here after I'll try to figure out the exact problem. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem too when I started out.

For my first app, the steps at [Provisioning unveiled](http://iosguy.com/2010/09/08/provisioning-unveiled/) worked perfectly for me.

The next thing you could try out is distributing your app [wirelessly](http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/06/22/ios-wireless-app-distribution/) (along with the provisioning profile), which gets very exciting :)

Answer (score 0):

The [tutorial](http://iosguy.com/2010/09/08/provisioning-unveiled/) linked by Hippo in his [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45679/115) looks perfectly fine, however it doesn't mention a small detail that Apple does. When you're in the step:

> Time to request your certificate. Open Spotlight and enter Keychain. Create a new certificate request.

Before you do the "Create a new certificate request", you should go to Keychain's preferences and in the Certificates Tab, turn off both OCSP and CRL.

[image]

After that, you can safely go to *Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority*.

Comment: Hey.. thanks to point out missing process. Kudos to you!!

Comment: No problem. Good luck with that. :)